# How to show different image on all the annotation pins on map?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have two locations, one starting point and another end point, on these two points i want to add two different pin annotation

this is my code, the problem is i m getting the same image on both the locations

**location is <+47.45025000,-122.30881700>
and location1 is <+47.62212000,-122.35410000>**

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapViewer viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    static NSString *mapIdentifier=@"mapIdentifier";

    MKAnnotationView *myAnnotation=[mapViewer dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:mapIdentifier];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D parkCllocation=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([_tripDetails[@"park_lat"] doubleValue], [_tripDetails[@"park_long"] doubleValue]);

    MKPointAnnotation *jauntAnnotationPark =[[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    // jauntAnnotationPark.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinks.jpg"];
    jauntAnnotationPark.coordinate=parkCllocation;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D orginCllocation=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([_tripDetails[@"origin_lat"] doubleValue], [_tripDetails[@"origin_long"] doubleValue]);

    MKPointAnnotation *jauntAnnotationOrgin =[[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    jauntAnnotationOrgin.coordinate=orginCllocation;
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[_tripDetails[@"origin_lat"] doubleValue] longitude:[_tripDetails[@"origin_long"] doubleValue]];

    CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[_tripDetails[@"park_lat"] doubleValue] longitude:[_tripDetails[@"park_long"] doubleValue]];

    myAnnotation = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:mapIdentifier];

    check=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:location,location1, nil];

    for (NSString *location in check)
    {

        int i;            
        myAnnotation.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin7@2x.png"];

    }

    if (!myAnnotation) {

        myAnnotation = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:mapIdentifier];

}
    else {
        myAnnotation.annotation=annotation;
    }

    return myAnnotation;
```

}

Comment: You only set one image - pin7. Also your code contains a lot of redundancy; you dequeue an annotation view into `myAnnotation` then alloc/init a new one then later you check if it is nil which it won't be because you just alloc/inited one. Your `check` array contains CLLocation objects but you iterate the array into an NSString reference - and don't do anything with the value anyway

Comment: then wat about the other pin image if i only add pin7 @Paulw11

Comment: I think what you want to do is set a different image depending on whether it is the start or end annotation, but you never actually perform that check

Comment: where and how to perform that check @Paulw11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code only sets one image - pin7 and your code also contains a lot of redundancy; you dequeue an annotation view into myAnnotation then alloc/init a new one then later you check if it is nil which it won't be because you just alloc/inited one.

Your check array contains CLLocation objects but you iterate the array into an NSString reference - and then don't do anything with the value anyway.

You can use this code to dequeue a view, allocate a new one if it can't be dequeued and then set the appropriate image; This code assumes that there are only two annotations and if it isn't the origin then it must be the end.  If there are more than these two annotations then you need modify the code to account for that.

```
 -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapViewer viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    static NSString *mapIdentifier=@"mapIdentifier";

    MKAnnotationView *myAnnotation=[mapViewer dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:mapIdentifier];

    if (myAnnotation == nil) {
        myAnnotation = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:mapIdentifier];
    }


    CLLocationCoordinate2D originCllocation=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([_tripDetails[@"origin_lat"] doubleValue], [_tripDetails[@"origin_long"] doubleValue]);

    if (originCllocation.latitude==annotation.coordinate.latitude && originCllocation.longitude==annotation.coordinate.longitude) {
       myAnnotation.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"startPin.png"];
    } else {
       myAnnotation.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"endPin.png"];
    }

    return myAnnotation;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Paulw11,now i m getting right images on start and end points.Now i have another array having some other locations i need to show them also with different images

Comment: It is just a matter of expanding the `if` statements to determine the type of image you should use

Comment: in if statement what condition i need to check,if i use annotation.coordinate.latitude then it goes inside all the if statements@Paulw11

Answer (score 1):

loop through the latitude and longitude values of your annotation coordinates.

and implement checks in view for annotation

```
for(int i=0; i <latArray.count; i++)
{

   //annotation.coordinate.latitude
   //annotation.coordinate.longitude
   //compare your latitude and longitude values and change the image accordingly.
}
```

Comment: i have lat n long so how to manage them in an array to show all the locations on map

Comment: as i mentioned loop through the array and check for particular lat long. otherwise you need to categorize your lat long array by making it multidimensional like. set a particular lat long and set category as Hotel , hospital and implement conditions on that basis of that

Comment: by adding this for loop i m getting the same image on all the locations.Plz help me out

Answer (score 0):

yup you can do it by putting condition also.

```
  -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapViewer viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {
    if (annotation.title.isEqualToString(@"Source"))
    {
        myAnnotation.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"startPin.png"];
       } else {
        myAnnotation.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"endPin.png"];
    }
```